# Fetching comments from active facebook ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I am working on a Facebook comment manager and I just can't manage to get only active ad creatives from Facebook API.

Is there a way to get all ad creatives filtered by their status?

I can't afford to check all ads manually, because I plan to pull ads every few minutes and I would be hitting Facebook's rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of endpoints that could help you do this, but would require you to make multiple API calls.

**Step One: Get all Ads**

Assuming you have managed to get the Ad Account ID from a previous API call, you will be able to get all Ads running against that account by making a GET request to the `/act_{ad_account_id}/ads?fields=name` endpoint.

**Step Two: Get Images with Active Status**

Next you can call the `/{ad_id}/adcreatives?fields=name,image_hash,status` endpoint for each Ad, which will return the name of the creative, the image hash that was used, and the status of the creative.

If you require the status of the actual Ad itself rather than the status of the creative, you will need to do another step in between Step One and Step Two, where you call `/{ad_id}?fields=name,status` on each Ad, then filter `ACTIVE` campaigns.

**EDIT:**

You can use `/act_{ad_account_id}/adcreatives?fields=status,image_hash,title` to get all creatives and statuses associated with the account. This would reduce your API call rate although would mean you would need to sort the creative to match with the ads. Using the title field would give the title of the ad it was used in the ad. Facebook does not offer any other fields related to the ad itself.

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, but as I said, I can't afford to parse individual ads because of rate limtis.
Currently there is few thousand ads and new ones are added every day.

Comment: @Sigismund if you don't care about specific ads, you can use `act_{ad_account_id}/adcreatives?fields=status,image_hash,title` to get all creatives and statuses associated with the account. This would reduce your API call rate although would mean you would need to sort the creative to match with the ads. Using the `title` field would give the title of the ad it was used in the ad. Facebook does not offer any other fields related to the ad itself.

Comment: The problem with ad creative status is that it doesn't represent status of ad / campaign. Campaign could be disabled, but ad creative would still have active status.

It seems that I approched this problem from wrong angle. I needed latest post/ads comment.
I decided to get latest comment activity on posts/ads via page notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit results to ads whose effective_status is ACTIVE.

Here is a sample request:

*act_123/ads?filtering=[{"field":"effective_status","operator":"IN","value":["PAUSED"]}]*

[Ad fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup#Reading)

[Insight Parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters)